# Python: Unable to install TA-lib in Oracle AArch64 VM ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, installation, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, ta-lib

I unable to Ta-lib, a module for technical analysis in python3 in an always free ARM 64(AArch64) Amepere processor with Ubuntu 20 from Oracle cloud. To verify if the steps I followed are correct, I manage to install successfully in a X64 VM with AMD processor. Thus, I tink AArch64 may need some tweak to install Ta-lib.

The steps I used are below (https://sachsenhofer.io/install-ta-lib-ubuntu-server/)

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib/
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

The error I found in my Ubuntu terminal for `./configure`  as below

```
<pre>
ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz                         100%[=====================================================================================================&gt;]   1.27M  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2021-09-02 09:32:28 (47.0 MB/s) - ‘ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz’ saved [1330299/1330299]

<font color="#55FF55"><b>ubuntu@algo3</b></font>:<font color="#5555FF"><b>~</b></font>$ tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
<font color="#55FF55"><b>ubuntu@algo3</b></font>:<font color="#5555FF"><b>~</b></font>$ cd ta-lib/
<font color="#55FF55"><b>ubuntu@algo3</b></font>:<font color="#5555FF"><b>~/ta-lib</b></font>$ sudo ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2006-07-02, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

  http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.guess
and
  http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.sub

If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please
send the following data and any information you think might be
pertinent to &lt;config-patches@gnu.org&gt; in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2006-07-02

uname -m = aarch64
uname -r = 5.8.0-1037-oracle
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #38~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 16 00:56:44 UTC 2021

/usr/bin/uname -p = aarch64
/bin/uname -X     = 

hostinfo               = 
/bin/universe          = 
/usr/bin/arch -k       = 
/bin/arch              = aarch64
/usr/bin/oslevel       = 
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = 

UNAME_MACHINE = aarch64
UNAME_RELEASE = 5.8.0-1037-oracle
UNAME_SYSTEM  = Linux
UNAME_VERSION = #38~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 16 00:56:44 UTC 2021
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
<font color="#55FF55"><b>ubuntu@algo3</b></font>:<font color="#5555FF"><b>~/ta-lib</b></font>$ 
</pre>
```

Comment: Try `autoreconf --install` before `./configure`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out having an installed x86_64 version of TA-Lib will interfere with the installation of the arm64 version of TA-Lib.
please uninstall the x86_64 version of TA-Lib using brew uninstall ta-lib first before installing the arm64 version of TA-Lib.

Some possible debugging:

```
➜  which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew

➜  brew --prefix ta-lib
/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib

➜  file $(brew --prefix ta-lib)/lib/libta_lib.dylib
/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/lib/libta_lib.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64

➜  which python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

➜  file /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64

➜  ~ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 26 2021, 15:28:17) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import talib
>>> talib.__ta_version__
b'0.4.0 (Nov 25 2020 22:11:03)'
```

Answer (score 0):

> checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type
> This script, last modified 2006-07-02, has failed to recognize
> the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
> download the most up to date version of the config scripts from
> http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.guess
> and http://savannah.gnu.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/config/config/config.sub

Just download the newsest config.guess config.sub from the source and repeat the configure & make install progress. ta-lib will install successfully.

```sh
ta-lib-config --version 
0.4.0
```